# What does the Qt5 -icu configure option do?

Tags: qt, desktop-application, qt5, icu

We have a desktop application built with Qt 4.8.4 which makes use of ICU.  I am now porting that application to Qt 5.2.1.  I notice a new configure option:  `-icu`.  What does this do?  I'm trying to determine if I should use it or not.

I've read that it "enables ICU support."  What does that mean?  And does that matter for porting an application that is already using ICU under 4.8.4?

In case it matters:  we plan to build on Windows, Mac OSX, and several Linux distros.

Note:  our application does not use webkit.

Comment: Qt5 is using ICU for unicode support. You may share ICU libraries between your code and Qt binaries

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, but I'm still not clear what it means that Qt5 is using ICU for unicode support.  Does that mean if I configure Qt5 with -icu, then Qt5 automatically includes some version (what version?) of ICU, and for instance whenever I use a QString, I can get the correct upper/lower case simply by using the QString API - no need for my current code that uses the ICU API?  And if I don't configure Qt5 with -icu, then I just keep using ICU the same way I used it under Qt4?

Comment: You will have full unicode support in Qt5 (based on ICU), so you don't need to use ICU directly for Qt strings.

Comment: So my options are:  if I want to refactor our code to take advantage of Qt5 wrapping ICU, I first need to build ICU, then configure Qt with -icu option?  Or else, if I just want to leave our code the way it is, I configure Qt without -icu?